# Como colocar uma imageView em formato Circular dentro de uma fragment Android?

Tags: android, android-fragment, imageview

Encontrei na net vários tutoriais em inglês com exemplos de métodos para arredondar uma imagem bitmap. Porem não consegui implementá-los dentro de uma fragment. Como proceder nesse caso?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No meu caso so consegui usar um fazer um `ImageView` redondo usando uma biblioteca externa, no caso meu caso a [CircleImageView](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).
Basta adicionar a dependencia no `Gradle`:

```
compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0'
```

E usar `CircleImageView` no lugar de `ImageView` no xml:

```
<de.hdodenhof.circleimageview.CircleImageView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="96dp"
    android:layout_height="96dp"
    android:src="@drawable/profile" // Sua imagem
    app:civ_border_width="0dp" // Se quiser pode colocar uma borda na imagem tambem
    app:civ_border_color="#FF000000"/> // Cor da borda
```

Para mais informações veja o link oficial da [API](https://github.com/hdodenhof/CircleImageView).

Comment: Desculpe a minha ignorância pois sou iniciante em java e android. Mas ao baixar essa biblioteca eu devo primeiro colar ela em algum lugar do meu projeto correto? Onde faço isso?

Comment: Usa o AndroidStudio?

Comment: Sim. Exatamente.

Comment: Basta clicar em build.gradle (Module: app) no canto esquerdo da tela, e adicionar a linha compile 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:2.0.0' em dependencies

Comment: Certo. Mas eu não preciso baixar a biblioteca que me passou pelo link e colar em algum lugar do meu projeto ou é só adicionar essa linha mesmo?

Comment: Essa linha é como se fosse um link para a biblioteca, ao adicionar ela, vai aparecer uma mensagem amarela no topo da tela escrito sync now, basta voce clicar nela (com internet, pois ele baixa uma vez) e pronto.

Comment: Ah entendi. Ok. Valeu amigo.

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite,

Eu tentei usar android.support.v4.widget.CircleImageView, mas não consegui, então uma solução que encontrei foi implementar a minha própria classe (MyCircleImageView) herdando de ImageView.
É uma classe bem simples e pequena. Pode ser utilizada no lugar de ImageView no layout.

```
/**
 * Created by jorlane on 15/05/17.
 */

public class MyCircleImageView extends ImageView {

private Paint paint;

...
Construtores (inicialização, cria o objeto paint)
... 

@Override
public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(2);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

    float largura = getWidth();
    float altura  = getHeight();

    float x = largura / 2;
    float y = altura / 2;
    float raio = 0;
    if (largura > altura) {
        raio = (altura)/2;
    } else {
        raio = (largura) / 2;
    }

    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, raio, paint);

    paint.setStrokeWidth(300);
    canvas.drawCircle(x, y, raio + 150, paint);
}
```